# install python modules on shared web hosting

Tags: python, compiler-construction

I am using a shared hosting environment that will not give me access to the command line.

Can I download the python module on my computer, compile it using `python setup.py install`and then simply upload a .py file to the web host?

If yes, where does the install statement place the compiled file?

Comment: This depends a lot on the hosting environment provided. Your best bet is to e-mail the support team directly.

Answer (score 2):

This is not directly an answer to your question but.. change your hosting provider! There are very cheap hostings with shell access and I swear that running Python site without access to shell is next to impossible.

Also, compiling Python library (I assume that it has some C bindings, otherwise there's not much to compile) on your local computer and uploading it to remote server without shell access might turn out to be a nightmare, because of some missing dependencies, conflicting versions of other libraries etc.

Last but not least, tools like [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org) are your friends during deployment to remote servers, and without shell access you basically either can't use them, or you suffer (for example: I have a script that commits&pushes local changesets to Mercurial repository on a remote server, updates it there and restarts that app on server - how would you do this with FTP-only access :) ?)..